# MAE ViT for inference

Tags: computer-vision, autoencoder, masking, transformer-model

I am using Meta's MAE-ViT model and pretrained it on my dataset. Since the output is not as I expected, I want to clarify the following question:
I have 14x14=196 patches per image. Using a mask-ratio of 0.8, I get ~39 patches as my input sequence length for pretraining. Can I expect meaningful output on other sequence lengths? More concrete: Is the returned dense representation meaningful when inputting all patches (sequence of 196)? Or would I still use the same mask ratio and random masking during inference?
If the sequence length is kind of fixed due to it's pretraining, how can I get a 'global' dense feature from my whole image? I want my finetuning task to be a inpainting process on each image region and measure the reconstruction error to find anomalies.
Thanks in advance!